# How to intersect sorted sets with specific score?

Tags: redis

tl:dr;
Can I do the intersection between two sorted sets, but only for the fields that have a specified score?
For example:

```
ZADD zset1 1 "first"
ZADD zset1 2 "second"
ZADD zset2 1 "first"
ZADD zset2 2 "second"

<command_that_I_need> <score> 2 zset1 zset2
```

And with score 1, would return:

```
1 "first"
```

---

### Why do I want to do this?

Why? I'll need to explain some things first.

In my model, there are `users`, which can create `articles`.
Each `article` is associated to an `article_id`.

I want to give anyone the ability to search for article `titles`, and optionally specifying the `user`.
And I thought of this by splitting the query in words, and finding which `articles` contain those words.

And I'm able to do that because I store that information this way:

```
zadd search_words:<word> <user_id> <article_id>
```

Each time an article is created, its title is split in `words`. For each `word` in `words`, I create that sorted set.

That way, I would split each query in words, and intersect the `search_words:<word>` sorted sets. And **I do want to filter by score because**  that would allow me to filter by `user_id`.

Note: Since the articles also have content, I'm aware that the user would want the search to look in the content, but that is out of the scope of my project, and thus I ignore that temporarily.
Note 2: Is there a better solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single command to do your bidding in this case. One way to go about it would be to first do the `ZINTERSTORE` on all your sets and then do a `ZRANGEBYSCORE` on the result to filter by your user_id.

Note 2: your use of sorted sets' score is acceptable since apparently user_id is numeric. However, a simpler way would be to use regular sets. You can continue using the same mechanism for the words and articles but instead of storing the article_id<->user_id relationship in a score, use a dedicated set for each user, for example:

```
SADD articles:<user_id> <article_id>
```

Then, to do your query for articles for specific words and a user, just do `SINTER[STORE]` like so:

```
SINTER articles:<user_id> search_words:<word1> search_words:<word2>...
```

Comment: That fits perfectly in the case I always filter by user. But sometimes I want to search all of them. I guess that I should have to store in the key `articles` a set containing **all** the `article_id`s, thus duplicating data. That's why I thought of keeping the score. What do you think?

Comment: If you want to search all articles by words, you don't need an articles superset - just intersect as above (without the user set of course).

Comment: How did I miss that. So simple and elegant, nosql is beautiful indeed.